# a long string overflow a div container

Tags: css, html, overflow

If "content" contains a long string without a space, it will overflow outside div("topic").
How could I fix this?

A live demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/w87Vz/

html:

```
<div class="topic">
    <div class="content">a longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong string</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.topic{
background:#ddd;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in your style add:
    word-wrap: break-word;